# Wireless networks not showing up on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, wifi, intel, wpa-supplicant

This is is continuation of [another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160029/how-do-i-enable-kernel-to-load-intel%C2%AE-wireless-7260-card-on-nuc-dc3217iye-with-d) that is resolved now.

Now I am actually struggling to get the list of wireless networks available. The Intel 7260 appears to be installed and detected properly, but any attempt to join the ESSID named "mar" fails. I have tried using `wpa_supplicant` (see further in the question description).

Note that I am able to get a list of networks using `iwlist scan` but No results using `wpa_cli list_networks` (see further). Which doesn't make a lot of sense to me as this is all pretty new to me.

### Environment

- Next Unit of Computing NUC DC3217IYE
- with Debian 3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64
- [867Mbps 802.11ac Intel 7260 card, Dual band 5GHz + 2.4GHz Wireless 2x2 AC + Bluetooth4.0](http://www.amazon.de/867Mbps-802-11AC-Intel-Original-Lenovo/dp/B00KVDSM06)

### dmesg

```
root@marvin:~# dmesg | grep wifi
[    2.793592] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.793814] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.801067] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
[    2.801353] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.222.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.816828] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    2.817506] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    2.817768] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    4.697179] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    4.697409] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
```

### iwconfig

```
# iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

### iwlist

```
 $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
 wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: F4:CA:E5:FE:60:D4
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"mar"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                              6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001c32228160
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3276ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00036D6172
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962C0C1218
                    IE: Unknown: 03010A
                    IE: Unknown: 050400020000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 3205243048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: F4:CA:E5:FE:60:D5
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"FreeWifi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                              6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001c32228160
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3240ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00084672656557696669
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962C0C1218
                    IE: Unknown: 03010A
                    IE: Unknown: 050401020000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 3205243048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6C0003FFFFFF0001000000000000000100000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160A001300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

### ip link

```
# ip link show wlan0
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:00:bc:79:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

### interfaces

```
# more /etc/network/interfaces 
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

### wpa_supplicant.conf

```
# more /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
network={
    ssid="mar"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    wep_key0=fffffffff
}


# wpa_cli reconfigure
Selected interface 'wlan0'
FAIL
```

### But most surprisingly whereas `iwlist scan` provides with a list of networks ??

```
# wpa_cli list_networks
Selected interface 'wlan0'
network id / ssid / bssid / flags

# wpa_cli status
Selected interface 'wlan0'
wpa_state=INACTIVE
address=00:15:00:bc:79:e2
```

### UPDATE

```
# ps -ef | grep wpa
/sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -t -ddd -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -C /var/run/wpa_supplicant


# wpa_cli scan_results
Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
f4:ca:e5:fe:60:d4   2457    -83 [WEP][ESS]  mar
f4:ca:e5:fe:60:d6   2457    -85 [WPA2-EAP-TKIP+CCMP][ESS]   FreeWifi_secure
f4:ca:e5:fe:60:d5   2457    -83 [ESS]   FreeWifi
```

But I am still not quite sure why `list_networks` returns no results (?) I must be misunderstanding usage.